# Customizing the macOS toolbar with Swift UI

Tags: macos, swiftui

I'm working on a macOS app, with the view layers written in SwiftUI. I know that  iOS toolbars can have the background color changed at least, but when I try to do this in macOS, it doesn't behave as I'd expect.

Here's a (simplified) example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Collections()
                .layoutPriority(0)
            
            Photos()
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 300, maxHeight: .infinity)
                    .background(Color.Alt.black)
                    .layoutPriority(1)
        }
        .toolbar {
            Toolbar().background(Color.red500)
        }
    }
}

struct Toolbar: View {
    var body: some View {
        Group {
            Slider(value: 250, in: 150...400) {
                Text("Toolbar.PreviewSize")
            } minimumValueLabel: {
                Image(systemName: "photo").resizable().scaledToFit().frame(width: 15)
            } maximumValueLabel: {
                Image(systemName: "photo").resizable().scaledToFit().frame(width: 23)
            } onEditingChanged: { _ in
                // do nothing
            }.frame(minWidth: 200)
                
            Spacer()
                    
            Text("Toolbar.SelectionCount")
                    
            Spacer()
                    
            AddPhotosButton()
        }
    }
}
```

Which produces something like this, which as you can see, doesn't apply the background color to the entire toolbar, just to the items in the toolbar:

[image: Toolbar with red background on the toolbar items, but not the entire toolbar]

I'm guessing I could make my own `WindowToolbarStyle` style, but there's no documentation on the protocol!

If I make my own toolbar as a `View` rather than with the `.toolbar` modifier, I can't read the safe area insets for the window traffic buttons when the sidebar is collapsed, resulting in a complete mess:

[image: custom toolbar that works well when the sidebar is open]
[image: custom toolbar that doesn't work when the sidebar is closed]

Thanks for any help!

Comment: you could try replacing `Group` with `HStack`, then add things like padding etc...

Comment: @workingdog that might work, but that feels a bit difficult to get the padding correct, and would be subject to any changes apple made in the future. I'd prefer an official path forward.

Comment: @Mike have you ever found a solution? Thanks!

Comment: @nrudnyk unfortunately not! I gave up and am using the default toolbar style from Apple for now. I haven't tried SwiftUI 3 yet, however, so it's possible that there is an opportunity with the new version coming out this fall.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue you're running into is that the toolbar has a "safe area" you need to explicitly ignore. This can be done with the following code.

```
.toolbar { 
     // your toolbar code 
}.background(Color.gray.ignoresSafeArea())
```

The `toolbarBackground` modifier only works for macOS 13.0 and above so it wouldn't be a general answer if you need backwards compatibility.

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of the previous answer. The last bit might be a useful comment on that existing answer; you'll be able to comment once you build a small amount of reputation.

Comment: Unfortunately this has the same/no effect. It displays the same as the original post screenshots. If I apply this to the `.toolbar` modifier, the background takes up the entire view, not just the toolbar.

Answer (score -1):

I recommend

```
{
.toolbar {
      Toolbar()
    }.toolbarBackground(Color.gray)
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: This doesn't match the [API signature](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/toolbarbackground(_:for:)-5ybst) at all